# Session ID PHP changes?

Tags: php, session

Ok so this is what im trying to do.
(I forgot to place the buttons that redirect but you get the idea)

on test1.php

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   echo session_id(); //prints 5e28459b687847200537d1acd5ee880f
   $_SESSION['test']=1;
   echo $_SESSION['test']; // prints 1
?>
```

on test2.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   echo session_id(); //print nothing
   echo $_SESSION['test']; // prints 1
?>
```

and here comes the problem:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<?php echo session_id(); //prints 5e28459b687847200537d1acd5ee880f5e28459b687847200537d1acd5ee880f(yes it duplicates)
      echo $_SESSION['test'] // prints none
?>
</html>
```

I've been trying to fix this because I can't pass my variables to the 3rd page or so, tried searching and saw none or maybe similar yet not quite and tried those did not work so I end up asking you all.

Comment: I don't see how your simple example could produce the output you've described. Sounds like you've whittled down your problem to just the pertinent components (good thing) but you may have removed too much.

Comment: My main problem is the session_id changes and im guessing that it has something to do with my session variables not being passed.

Comment: The only way a session id can change is if: 1. You changed it yourself  with `session_id()`. 2. You changed it with `session_regenerate_id()`. 3. You changed the PHPSESSID cookie. 4. You destroy the session and PHP starts a new one.

Comment: Answer to all those are no, im trying to figure out why even the echo session_id loops

Comment: Well it's impossible for the 3 files you posted to do what you're describing them as doing. Feel free to whip up a reproducible example so the rest of us can follow along http://sscce.org/

Comment: '@2. The session_id is gone but the `$_SESSSION` variable is set?? Bet you have some output in `test2.php` before `session_start()` (and that `$_SESSION` is not set for sure).

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line into php.ini:

```
session.auto_start = on
```

or put this into your apache virtual-site config or .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag session.auto_start on
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You've described how to start sessions automatically. How does that help his session id issue?

Comment: I noticed a php.ini configuration setting that causes php to auto-start the session upon every request. It's an alternative to placing session_start() onto every page...

Comment: He has session_start() at the top of every file. Are we just posting random tips on session usage?